# REST API endpoint when there is only ever one record

Tags: rest

I'm writing a RESTful webservice to upsert and fetch my application's configuration.  There will only ever be one document/record, as this is global configuration.  My question is how do I fit this into RESTful standards?

For the upsert, is a controller method of "create" or "update" most appropriate (and a verb of POST or PUT respectively)?

For the fetch, is a controller method of "index" or "show" more correct?  If the former, is it acceptable to return a single object or should it be an array with a length of one?  For the latter, would it be acceptable to have the route exclude the id parameter (since there's always one and it's not necessary)?

Am I overthinking this, or putting too much emphasis on "REST compliance/consistency"? Or maybe the entire thing is wrong, and I shouldn't be writing this service. I should mention that this API is more internal than anything, just what our front-end uses to communicate with the back-end.  So while there's no third-parties to worry about, I still want the maintenance developer to not be confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are overthinking it.

Comment: You can return a single object, this is not a collection. You don't need id either. I would use PUT for upsert and GET to read info. You don't need more I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem. Here's how I would design this API:

- `GET /api/configuration` - get the configuration
- `PUT /api/configuration` - update the configuration
- `PATCH /api/configuration` - partially update the configuration

Comment: When what you are trying to do is pure document manipulation, the mapping to the HTTP method set is usually trivially correct.